# I'm trying to identify this WiFi / Microcontroller without any luck

Tags: microcontroller, identification, wifi

I purchased these [TanTan Smart electrical outlets](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B071VYFJRL) with the hopes of finding an esp8285 or esp8266 within them.  When I opened one up I was greeted by  something different, and am trying to determine what it is before exploring further.

The model numbers and QR code on the chip have turned up no results:
[image]
[image]

Exploring the rest of the smart socket I'm presuming the chip is a combined Wifi + Microcontroller + ROM, as the rest of the product appears to be simple components--a relay to switch the power, a switch and LED for user input/output, and a handful of capacitors, resistors, a thermistor, etc--no other ICs or chips.

The keywords I've tried are things like:
T201-V1.0
109-002-0029
Model: WP3-B
ZG PCB
ZG PCB Logo
2.4ghz WiFi WP3-B T201-V1.0

None have provided any relevant results.  So, I'm hoping to get an identification, or at least a strong lead.  What chip is this?

PS: [Here's a peek at the rest of the product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9U5Ky.png)

Comment: Really ugly thing. You should post these pictrures on Amazon, at least no other people would get stealed.

Comment: It's probable that the module is not listed in the internet (not so rare with large manufacturers). That said: can you decode the QR Code? And also can you remove the sticker and make a photo of what's under it?

Comment: Also can you trace the other end of those RX/TX wires? It should have another IC, possibly an MCU.

Comment: what is the MAC address?

Comment: @JanDorniak I tried scanning the QR code with no results (seemed odd to not at least get a text-result).  I peeled off the sticker and found no text under--just a blank shield.  I'm still working on removing the rest of the packaging/mains pins but I'm 99% sure there isn't a seperate IC/MCU.

Comment: @STW where would the RX/TX lines lead to then? Maybe the QR code is binary? Yes, they can be.

Comment: @JanDorniak they aren't connected.  They were soldered to pads, but under closer inspection the pads go nowhere

Comment: The QR code is the serial number

Comment: you could try https://github.com/arendst/Sonoff-Tasmota. could to be the same as an gosund sp111 / BlitzWolf SHP2 (german link: https://www.bastelbunker.de/gosund-sp1-mit-tasmota/)

Comment: i just opened an gosund sp1-C-v2.3 and there is the same chip inside -- and it works with tasmota. i am just trying to get the configuration right

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trick question... it turns out it is indeed an esp8285.  I carefully removed the heatshield and found the MCU clearly labeled:

[image]

Comment: I was right now looking into Espressif modules, because of io pin numbers from 0 to 5 and from 12 to 14. and A0

Comment: it is an ESP-01M